# Is there a compiled list of merchants that are taking lightning network payments for testing?

Tags: lightning-network, merchants

How many merchants are adopting lightning network payments? And is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

- Not many it seems.
- How about [this list](http://lightningnetworkstores.com/)?